# Mobile app logging stats tools - Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am developing a mobile GPS tracking app and I would like to know if there are any classes available that output the mobile stats to a view? Memory, CPU etc. Similar to Hi-res-Stats in AS3.

I would like to see usage while the app is used however the only tool I know of is built in to xcode and it wouldn't really be feasible taking my mac with me.

Thanks